# SQL - invalid column name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
SELECT o.outcode AS lead_postcode, v.outcode AS venue_postcode, 6 * o.lat AS distance 
FROM venue_postcodes v, uk_postcodes o 
WHERE o.outcode = 'CF3' 
GROUP BY v.outcode 
HAVING SUM(distance)>100 
ORDER BY distance
```

This stopped working when I added the part `GROUP BY v.outcode HAVING SUM(distance)>100`

It says **Server was unable to process request. ---> Invalid column name 'distance'**.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "alias" distance only just defined within the query as "6*o.lat" can not yet be used within the query but only afterwards.

alternative solution is

```
SELECT i.*
FROM (
  SELECT o.outcode AS lead_postcode, v.outcode AS venue_postcode, 6 * o.lat AS distance 
  FROM venue_postcodes v, uk_postcodes o 
  WHERE o.outcode = 'CF3' 
) i
GROUP BY i.outcode 
HAVING SUM(i.distance)>100 ORDER BY i.distance
```

Answer (score 6):

`distance` is a column alias and you can't refer to a column alias in a `HAVING` clause. But you can use aliases in an `ORDER BY`.

Try changing to:

```
HAVING SUM(6 * o.lat)>100 
ORDER BY distance
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ORDER BY 6 * o.lat`. You cannot use the clause AS for an `ORDER BY`

Comment: Not totally true... see dogbane's comment.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use SUM(6* o.lat), because not every database server can use aliased columns in having clause (It has to do with query planning, parsing etc.). Depends on what DB you use.